# Why tetragonal Tanabe-Sugano diagram is not just a splitting of octahedral one?

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, spectroscopy, crystals, orbitals

It is known that electron energy levels will be split when the symmetry reduces. For example, $T_1$ symmetry will split into $E$ and $A_2$ when the octahedral crystal field has a tetragonal distortion. Then naively the tetragonal crystal field energy diagram should be just the splitting of octahedral crystal field one. But according to Tanabe-Sugano diagrams it is not the case, why is that? Thank you!